# Running Spring integration tests with @NoRepositoryBean with no @Repository implementation

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test

I have a situation where I have a few modules, with the primary module being datastore agnostic. There are child modules that depend on the primary module with repository implementations for JPA and Mongo.

- `Core-Module` - All business logic, `@NoRepositoryBean` interfaces
- `Core-Mongo` - Dependent on `Core-Module` with Mongo repositories/domain
- `Core-JPA` - Dependent on `Core-Module` with JPA repositories/domain

Essentially, what I'd like to do is have integration tests in `Core-Module` use an H2 database to perform the tests and not be dependent on a `@Repository` implementation.

I realize I could make test-only `@Repository` interfaces, and that may be the route I have to go, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way. Essentially, is there a way to "instantiate" a `@NoRepositoryBean` in tests or some other simple way to do this without having to declare test only repositories?

Comment: Not even sure this feasible... even getting around this, I require a domain class to map fields and columns to a DB.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked this interest question. I marked in my test project `UserRepository` by `@NoRepositoryBean`, after that in test i unable to autowired it. But in documentation [spring-docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.create-instances.standalone) i found java creation repositories process description, and it's works perfect. Just before test create required repositories. 
Piece of test code example:

```
  private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    JpaRepositoryFactory factory = new JpaRepositoryFactory(entityManager);
    userRepository = factory.getRepository(UserRepository.class);
  }
```